# Search for substrings in files, but only examine first few characters

Tags: windows, powershell, grep

I have a list of keywords I want to search for, say `FOO, BAR, BAZ`, and a large amount of files of various size, which might include one of the aforementioned keywords at the very start of the file. Such a file might look like this:

```
AAA:+.? 'BBB+1234567890000+9999999999999+FOO'CCC+...
```

Those are `'`-separated segments. The keywords I want to search for can only occur in the second segment (the `BBB`-part), so I could either split by `'` or just search the first 100 bytes or so. It doesn't have to be precise, and false positives are not a concern either.

I am restricted to using tools available on Windows by default, so I assumed Powershell was the best way to go. I could perform a fulltext search using [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7), but given that a lot of the files are of very large size, to have acceptable performance I do not want the entire file to be read.

How could I find all files that contain any of a given set of keywords at their beginning without performing a fulltext search on each file's entire contents?

Comment: I see `grep` among your tags. Is that on purpose? You **can** install a `bash` clone and most GNU utilities on a Windows machine (something like "ubuntu on windows" if I remember correctly, you can Google around to find out) - perhaps you already have done this. In any case, `grep` is indeed the best way to solve this kind of problem - just making sure you actually meant it.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Thanks, yes I included the tag on purpose. Although not because I could use grep, but because a grep solution might still help me in finding a powershell solution, and it might help others that are not constraint to just using tools that ship with windows. I am restraint from installing any additional software on the machines I need to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by manually iterating over all files, reading only a couple of bytes (the files I need to analyze are ASCII, if they were unicode this likely won't work for all cases), and see if it matches

```
$keywords = @("FOO", "BAR", "BAZ")

Get-ChildItem -Path "*.*" -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    # only read 500 bytes. needs byte encoding as -TotalCount otherwise gets interpreted as number of lines
    $bytes = Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding byte -TotalCount 500
    # turn content back into string
    $content = [char[]]($bytes) -join ''

    $keywords | Foreach-Object {
        if ($content -match $_) {
            Write-Output "$($_): $($_.FullName)";
        }
    }
}
```